# ONNX Quantized Model Type Error: Type 'tensor(float16)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, onnx, onnxruntime

I converted onnx model from float32 to float16 by using this script.

```
from onnxruntime_tools import optimizer
optimized_model = optimizer.optimize_model("model_fixed.onnx", model_type='bert_tf', num_heads=12, hidden_size=768, opt_level=99)
optimized_model.use_dynamic_axes()
optimized_model.convert_model_float32_to_float16()
optimized_model.save_model_to_file("model_fixed_fp16.onnx")
```

But at the time of inference I am getting this error.

```
[ONNXRuntimeError] : 10 : INVALID_GRAPH : Load model from 
./model_fixed_fp16.onnx failed:This is an invalid model. 
Type Error: Type 'tensor(float16)' of input parameter 
(conv2d_1/convolution__24:0) of operator (Conv) in node (batch_normalization_1/FusedBatchNormV3_1:0_nchwc) is invalid
```

Also I changed the input dtype to float 16 by using this

```
pimage = np.array(np.expand_dims(pimage, axis=0), dtype=np.float16)
```

but still getting same error. What I have to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the conversion script here:
https://github.com/microsoft/onnxconverter-common/blob/master/onnxconverter_common/float16.py

If you still get an issue, open an issue on that repo.